# Is there a way to automate the monitoring and termination of AWS ECS tasks that are silently progressing?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I've been using AWS Fargate for quite a while and have been a big fan of the service.

This week, I created a **monitoring dashboard** that details the latest runtimes of my containers, and the timestamp watermark of each of my tables (the MAX date updated value). I have **SNS topics set up to email me whenever a container exits with code 1.**

However, I encountered a tricky issue today that slipped past these safeguards because of what I suspect was a **deadlock situation related to a Postgres RDS instance.**

I have several tasks running at different points in the day on a scheduler (usually every X or Y hours). Most of these tasks will perform some business logic calculations and **insert / update an RDS instance.**

One of my tasks (when checking the Cloudwatch logs later) was stuck making an update to a table, and basically just hung there waiting. My guess is that a user (perhaps me) - was manually making a small update statement to the same table, triggering some sort of lock that.

Because I have my tasks set on a recurring basis, **the same task had another container provisioned a few hours later, attempted to update the same table, and also hung.**

I only noticed this issue because my monitoring dashboard showed that the date updated watermark was still a few days in the past, even though I hadn't gotten any alerts or notifications for errors during my container run time. By this time, I had 3 containers all running, each stuck on the same update to the same table.

After I logged into the ECS console, I saw that my cluster had 3 task instances running - all the same task, all stuck making the same insert.

So my questions are:

- **is there a way to specify a runtime maximum** for these tasks (ie. if the task doesn't finish within 2 hours, terminate with an exit code of 1)?
- I'm trying to figure out **the best way to prevent this type of "silent failure" in the future**? I've added in application logic to execute a query checking for blocked process IDs with queries within my RDS instance, and if it notices any blocked PIDS, it skips the update. But are there any more graceful ways of detecting and handling this issue?

Comment: I'd first suggest to [configure timeouts on PostgreSQL side](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/164450/9060). I'd also recommend disabling noautocommit in your GUI client software.

It wasn't a deadlock - it was ordinary lock. A deadlock would resolve itself automatically in like a minute.